# React native view layer trick

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have a question about `View` component and it's kind of react native layer structure. Look at the following codes:

```
<View>
  <Image /> //this is my background image.
  <View></View> //this is just making a border.
  <Image /> //this is my small logo image with .png format.
</View>
```

This is how it's look:

[image]

So what I want is when I put my `logo image` component on `border`, the `border` that is intersecting with `logo image` must be invisible. On the other hand, other parts of `border` must be visible. Is it possible to make? If it is possible, how can i make that?

Comment: i met that case in the past. here is my solution: set border top,left,right for <View>, and use pseudo css for the logo image. you can try it

Comment: css pseudo classes not working with react-native, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

SVG can solve your problem. [Expo SVG page](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/svg/) has a useful example and tips.

Comment: Yeah good suggestion but I forgot to mention; my logo image and border are dynamic. I mean I can change both of sizes. So I can make compatible my logo image and border by your suggestion in many cases but sometimes it won't be compatible. For example; my logo can be very wide or very small.